# How to link to an AI question on MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion

MathOverflow has a nice [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439652/perceptron-logistic-regression-accuracy-on-the-n-bit-parity-problem) about the n-bit XOR accuracy of a linear perceptron. Should it be imported somehow to AI.SE or otherwise linked?

Comment: The question could be migrated to our site, but I think it's also fine to leave it there, because it's asking for a proof. In general, I would encourage any theoretical AI question to be asked on our site, but, unfortunately, many people still don't use our site to ask questions like the one you're mentioning. I'd love to see more of those questions on our site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We generally don't migrate questions unless they're off-topic on the site where they were originally asked. In this case, the question appears to be on-topic on MathOverflow, so migration to AI.SE isn't really on the table.

Unfortunately, the cross-site linking and information sharing capabilities of the SE network are currently somewhat lacking. There's no real way to keep the question on MO and also have it linked somewhere here; such a feature simply doesn't exist.

The question will show up on MO for someone searching for this question, though, and it's not like we're strangers to having AI-related content be spread out over several different sites. AI content can be found on Stack Overflow, Cross Validated, Open Data, and other SE sites. Until and unless SE improves its cross-site linking of related topics, it's just something we're going to have to live with.